# Can we use pigz with --zip to compress multiple files in single zip-compatible format?

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, zip

I am trying to figure out a way to use parallel compression to zip using `pigz`, but couldn't find a way till now.

One option I have is to zip files/dirs with `zip -r -0` and then again use `pigz -K -f`, but it creates a zip inside the zip.

I came across an upvoted answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/748170/1183157) which seemed like a solution but had invalid `zip`-like syntax for `pigz`:

> ```
> pigz -K -k archive.zip bigfile txt
> ```

I don't think `pigz` takes zip file name as an argument and we can then specify the files to zip.

Comment: My original problem why I wanted this is - I am creating zip archives with a few large files basically partition images for android to be installed in recovery, hence tar or zip in zip is not something I want. There are some small files along with 2 large partitions system.img and vendor.img of 3G and 1G respectively. I am doing this on a 16-core CPU and zip is just using 1 core 100% and takes forever.

Comment: Then I tried `7za` which compresses individual files in parallel, so it uses 2 cores until `vendor.img` is finished and then becomes same as zip or slower for rest of the `system.img`.

`pigz --zip` on other hand though only works on single files is much much faster and uses many cores at the same time and compresses `system.img` for example in 1/10 time compared to others.

So, as of now, what I am doing is, I use `pigz --zip` to compress largest 3G file, rename the output zip and then use `zip -g` or `7za a` to add other files to the archive.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think `pigz` takes zip file name as an argument and we can then specify the files to zip.

It seems you're right.

---

> Can we use `pigz` with `--zip` to compress multiple files in a single zip-compatible format?

Probably not; or not yet (new features can be added in the future, although adding this particular feature may not be the Right Thing; keep reading). I have found no way to do this. You need to put your files into a single archive first, then compress.

There's a reason for this. According to the Unix philosophy programs should follow the "Do One Thing And Do It Well" rule. Putting one or more files (directory is also a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)) is one thing and we call it "archiving". Reducing the size is another thing and we call it "compressing". We have archivers, the common one is `tar`, the POSIX one is `pax`; and we have compressors: `gzip`, `compress`, `bzip2`, `lzma`, …

Some compressors and compressed file formats support storing multiple files because their authors were apparently not enlightened by the Unix philosophy. :)

But it's not only a philosophical issue, there are practical advantages:

- You can use any archiver with any compressor. In particular you can pick another (e.g. better) compressor and still use the archiver you are most familiar with (probably GNU `tar`). Tools that work as both tend to invent their own options and rules for the common task of archiving.
- If filesystems introduce new features then we will need to upgrade our archivers only.
- If you invent a new compression method then you will be able to develop a new compressor without paying attention to how to traverse directory trees, what metadata to read or [which character should](https://superuser.com/q/544786/432690) [separate pathname components](https://superuser.com/q/1382839/432690).

`pigz` is a compressor and it seems it has no ambition to be an archiver. With `--zip`/`-K` it uses the `.zip` *format* associated with a tool that is designed to be a compressor and an archiver. `pigz` doesn't have to use all the features of the format, in particular the ability to store more than one file. It could be "improved" but now you know why I think this wouldn't be the Right Thing.

Still archiving-*and*-compressing is a pretty common use case. A good archiver should be able to write to its stdout. A good compressor should be able to read from its stdin. Then you can use them in a pipeline. This is a general way.

Specifically with `tar` you can use a switch that makes the tool filter (pipe) the archive through a compressor: `-z` for `gzip`, `--lzma` for `lzma` etc. A universal switch is `-I`, it allows you to use a *custom* compressor. The compressor can be `pigz --zip`:

```
tar -cv -I 'pigz --zip' -f archive.tar.zip file1 file2 file3
```

The same compressor can be used to unpack, if only it supports `-d` (`pigz` does):

```
tar -xv -I 'pigz --zip' -f archive.tar.zip
```

Technically this `archive.tar.zip` is a zip file with a tar file inside, so it's similar to your "zip inside zip". If you `unzip` it then you will get a tar archive named `-`. The above `tar` commands work on the fly though (no intermediate file created).

This is how you do it in Linux/Unix.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it is indeed very helpful and clears the doubt along with some new information which I didn't know before.